A paradox on eulers equation
Consider eulers equation in $R^n$ :
$u_t+(u∇)u=-∇p$
div$(u)=0$
$u(0,x)=u_0$
If $n=3$ it is easy to show : $(u∇)u=1/2 ∇u^2+(∇×u)×u$. Let’s consider that $u_0=∇ϕ_0,ϕ_0∈C^∞$; of course we have div$(u_0 )=∆ϕ_0=0$. Meaning that the initial conditions come from a gradient. It is reasonable to try a solution of the form $u=∇ϕ$ . Now simply replecing I get:
$u_t+(u∇)u=u_t+1/2 ∇u^2+(∇×u)×u=∇ϕ_t +1/2 ∇(∇ϕ)^2$
Where $×$ is the cross product
Replecing in eulers equation:
$(∇ϕ_t +1/2 ∇(∇ϕ)^2=-∇p$ and $ ∆ϕ=0$ and $∇ϕ(0,x)=∇ϕ_0$
The first equation becomes:
$ϕ_t+(∇ϕ)^2=-p$
This is a scalar equation in p with the obvious solution.
$∆ϕ=0$ and $∇ϕ(0,x)=∇ϕ_0$
The abobe equation has MULTIPLE solutions $ϕ(t,x)=f(t) ϕ_0 (x)$. Notic that $f$ is arbitrary and can be  C^∞
So a solution to eulers equation is: $u(x,t)=f(t)∇ϕ_0 (x)$. This first implies that there are infinitly many smooth solutions, which is weird in itself, but it gets worst
If we go back and multiply by $u$ we get:
$u∙u_t+u∙1/2 ∇u^2+u∙(∇×u)×u=-u∙∇p$
$u∙(∇×u)×u=0$ by basic algebra. Integrating by parts with respect to spac and using div $(u)=0$; assuming thet $|u|→0$ as $|x|→0$ I get:
$\frac{d}{dt} ∫_{R^3} u^2  dx=0$
So then:
$∫_{R^3}u^2(t,x)dx=∫_{R^3} u^2  (0,x)dx=∫_{R^3}u_0^2 (x) dx$
This if in contradiction with : $u(x,t)=f(t)∇ϕ_0 (x)$ if we assume again the same initial codition. So what am I doinf wrong ?

I have an answer. First note that a assumption has to be made, that
$∫_{R^3}(∇ϕ)^2(t,x)dx<c$. Other wise some terms will not make sence.
So the problem are the 2 conditions: $∆ϕ=0$ and $∫_{R^3}(∇ϕ)^2(t,x)dx<c$. So visit this post and see that if both the mentioned conditions are satisfied we have that $ϕ=0$. This comes from the harmonic property of ϕ. Since ϕ is harmonic it's value at some $x$ is given by it's avarage over an arbitrary ball. However the condition $∫_{R^3}(∇ϕ)^2(t,x)dx<c$ implies that ϕ has to get smaller and smaller. Again visit the afformetioned post. Now that we know this all the terms that were providing contradictions are zero
This means that the only posible innitial condition ( that comes from a gradient) is $∇ϕ_0=0$. So the the contradiction are solved

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
